# How can one best visualize a measurable cardinal?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, large-cardinals

I've searched the web for several years attempting to find an intuitive and visualizable explanation of what measurable cardinals are and how best to conceive of them.

All I've found are definitions. For example: a two-valued measure on a cardinal $\kappa$, or more generally, on any set. A cardinal, $\kappa$, can be described as a subdivision of all of its subsets into large and small sets such that

1. $\kappa$ itself is large
2. $\varnothing$  and all singletons $\{\alpha\}, \alpha \in \kappa$ are small
3. Complements of small sets are large and vice versa
4. The intersection of fewer than $\kappa$ large sets is again large​.

I know what these various terms mean, but that doesn't help me:

a. Visualize what a measurable cardinal looks like

b. Know how one makes a measurable cardinal

c. Understand how Ulam first "discovered" -- or "invented"? -- them by working on the Lebesgue measure problem troubling everyone in the late 1920s

d. Know whether they can all still be reached by some Beth cardinal, say Beth omega, or Beth c -- presumably not!

e. Know why they have the amazing properties they do including that of being vastly larger than all of the inaccessible cardinals below them

Comment: Your question is *extremely* hard to read. I think some paragraph breaks would help tremendously.

Comment: For me it's hard enough to visualize $\omega,$ the smallest measurable cardinal (unless you count $0,1$ and $2.$) Well, I visualize $\omega$ itself as a line of dots trailing off into the distance, but I can't begin to visualize a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\omega.$

Comment: Thanks so much for cleaning up what I wrote so it is much easier to see what the various related questions are!

Answer (score 10):

In mathematics you don't understand things, you get used to them, to quote von Neumann.

Measurable cardinals, and really any large cardinal property, are definitions that are nearly impossible to visualize in any meaningful way. There are two reasons for this:

1. We are not very good at visualizing sets without structure, so we are not very good at visualizing the set theoretic universe, and the membership relation between the set. Not to mention that it gets *very* complicated, *very* fast, making it nearly impossible to fully appreciate.
2. Large cardinals are ***huge*** in comparison to sets that you normally think of. So large, that however large you think they might be, they are probably much larger. Every first-order definition which you could think of describing an inaccessible cardinal has already occurred at a lot of cardinals below it. Every *second-order* definition you might want to consider giving you a measurable cardinal has given you *a lot* of cardinals below it satisfying this definition.

   In particular, you need third-order logic to truly say that $\kappa$ is a measurable cardinal in the structure $V_\kappa$ (and that makes sense, as a measure is an object which lies in $V_{\kappa+2}$).

So how can you understand it? Well. You have to use measurable cardinals for a while, and get comfortable with them.

Just like understanding integrals as the area or volume of something is helpful intuition, but ultimately, you can integrate functions that have no reasonable "visual representation", so what sense could your brain make of volume and area they graph encloses? Well. You have a definition, and you work with it, and you got used to it, and everything is fine. Same with continuity, or determinants, or partitions of a set, or an arbitrary function being injective.

At first the definition was cumbersome, and you didn't quite get it. Maybe you made some mistakes, and maybe you didn't. But you worked slowly with the definitions and theorems until you got the feel of what these things are used for, and then you developed an image in your head.

So what about measurable cardinals? Well. There is a definition, which you cite. There is a free $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. That's it. Then you can start using this for actually proving things, like $V\neq L$, or the generic absoluteness of $\Sigma^1_3$ sentences, and after you've proved a bunch of things using measurable cardinals, you get better at understanding what they might be. But you can't quite give this intuition away to people. The most you can do is explain what these cardinals are useful for, and try and guide the development of that intuition in other people. (And again, this is true for *everything* in mathematics, not just large cardinals or set theory.)

Comment: I've always disagreed with that quote. It feels lazy.

Comment: Interesting. I find it to be more and more true as I expand my knowledge.

Comment: Note that such hugeness results presumably assume Choice. ​ Under Determinacy, for example, $\omega_1$ is already measurable. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky: Yes, under the "weak" definition of measurable anyway.

Comment: Thanks do much for your thoughtful answer, Asaf!!  I realized immediately that [e.] had a mistake in it, since obviously the measurable cardinals are themselves strongly inaccessible.  I have, however, seen claims -- clearly mistaken -- about the relative sizes of other strongly inaccessibles and measurables which leave one with the impression that however one might try to use recursive, or better infinitely repeated operations, like the power set operations etc., you still can't get to the measurables, which is, of course, just what "strongly inaccessible" means.  Is there a simple proof?cont

Comment: @WdFusroy: Well, there is no proof since you haven't described to me what are the rules I am allowed to use in this operation (e.g. $\omega$ or the least measurable above $\alpha$ is an operation, but certainly not the one you intend). But in general most of these operations tend to be absolute in the sense that they would work the same in every "sufficiently good" model, which in this case I mean every model that is correct about power sets (which makes it automatically some $V_\alpha$). Then you just can't go beyond inaccessible cardinals because of this absoluteness issue.

Comment: As to [d.] I am confused about what determines whegther a cardinal is an aleph?  If every infinite cardinal is an aleph, that would make it simply redundant to add that fact to each one of them.  I think the problem may be that I had thought that the alephs were simply the infinite series of power sets of power sets of Aleph0 etc.  Those lead to Aleph0 ^ aAleph0 performed Aleph0 times,or Aleph0 tetrated to Aleph0.  I'm not sure what the name of that particular cardinal is, but obviously it is significant.  But is it right to link the Aleph designation only with the power set operation + CH?

Comment: Your comments on [b.] are very ingteresting to me,  They also seem to move to what I would consider a more intuitve ex[planation of the measurables, since the concept of embedding is easier to grasp, at least for me, than trying to imagine and picture what all the various subsets of such a monster might be, or whagt one gets when including all of their infinite intersections etc.  So thanks for that. It helps1

Comment: You didn't answer [d.] but I included it sinmply as a possible way to figure out how it was that concept of a measurable cardinal was ever conceived by Ulam in the first place, hoping that do so might indicate how we too can grasp the notion. Clearly one wouldn't come up with such a, to me bizarre concept, and complex definitions unles one needed to.  So what was it that motivated Ulam?  Or, more simply, what can one understand by using the measurable cardinal concept that you couldn't  otherwise understand?  [This is also a question I have about other large caridinals, but one at a time!]

Comment: Assuming choice every infinite cardinal is an $\aleph$. Yes. Not assuming choice, this would depend on your definition of "cardinal", but the $\aleph$ numbers are still the cardinals of the infinite sets which can be well-ordered. I think that you should learn more about basic set theory before trying to tackle large cardinals, though.

Comment: As to your comments on many mathematical concepts also being very difficult to visualize, that is certainly true. Even some of the more geometrical set theory concepts, like say the Heine-Borel Theorem, seem tricky at first. And it is also true that working with such concepts does somehow render them a bit more comprehensible. But my problem is that since I don't have much of a clue what the things actually are I am also incapable of working with them. No matter how many times I have tried to grasp the various parts of the definition, however, I still can't see anything that forms a whole.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your helpful comments!!! I will now go back and study set "embeddings" since that may well prove more fruitful to me than spinning my wheels on the decidedly cumbersome definitions alone.

Comment: @WdFusroy: I wouldn't call Heine–Borel a set theoretic concept. Also, http://karagila.org/2017/dangerous-knowledge-in-the-information-age/

Comment: Here's another way of putting my original problem with the concept of a "measurable cardinal." In the definition I cited it claims that: "A [measurable] cardinal, κ, can be described as a subdivision of all of its subsets into large and small sets such that" ... the four conditions listed obtain. Are these "subsets" themselves the elements, whose total number is k?  If so, k must be < the Power set of k. What KIND of set is k then? How is it composed? Clearly it can't be, say, just subsets of R^n, since R^n has a PS = 2^c, which is hardly HUGE. Of what then is k itself composed?

Comment: @WdFusroy: Seriously, it is amazing that you want to know more about set theory and understand large cardinals. But the more you write, the more it becomes apparent that you lack a lot of very basic understanding about set theory. Where did you even come across the notion of a measurable cardinal to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

Let me address (e), (d), (b) in that order.

(e) is wrong: measurables are *not* greater than every strongly inaccessible cardinal. (For example, every measurable is itself strongly inaccessible!) A measurable is, however, greater than *lots* of strongly inaccessible cardinals - in fact, if $\mu$ is measurable then there are $\mu$-many strongly inaccessible cardinals $<\mu$.

I'm not sure what (d) means. *Every* cardinal is an $\aleph$-number (assuming choice), and in particular $\mu=\aleph_\mu$ for every measurable $\mu$. But that by itself isn't very mysterious - there are rather small cardinals satisfying $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$.

For (b), the way one gets a measurable cardinal is (usually) via an *elementary embedding of the universe into (some part of) itself*. This is a bit technical, but I think it's worth stating, and either Jech or Kanamori can fill in the details and provide more information:

If there is some class $M\subset V$ and some map $j:V\rightarrow M$ which is a nontrivial elementary embedding of $(V,\in)$ into $(M, \in\upharpoonright M)$, then (easy exercise) there is some least ordinal $\kappa=crit(j)$ such that $j(\kappa)>\kappa$. This turns out to be a measurable cardinal - specifically, the set $$\{X\subseteq \kappa: \kappa\in j(X)\}$$ is a measure on $\kappa$ for $\kappa=crit(j)$ (hard exercise). So one way to say "there is a measurable cardinal" is "there is a nontrivial elementary embedding of the universe into some inner model." And this in fact is how many higher large cardinal properties are usually stated and motivated: as asserting the existence of an embedding, or family of embeddings, with certain properties (where the large cardinal in question is (usually) the critical point of the embedding(s)). (Interestingly, [there can be no proper elementary embedding $V\rightarrow V$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunen%27s_inconsistency_theorem), so there is a limit to how far this idea can be pushed before it explodes.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99736/discussion-on-answer-by-noah-schweber-how-can-one-best-visualize-a-measurable-ca).